# Sub domain validation and creation from backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

Hi i have an application in which user registers and provide company name and i will use that name and create a sub domain which will get saved in company table. Now i want to make it unique as i don't want to restrict user to type same company name which is already in the database. I want that if company name is already present for example: name entered is **XYZ** so sub domain will be **xyz.myapp.com**, and when any other user type  the same name than sub domain should be **xyz1.myapp.com** and same for other same names in sequence.

Here i have tried some but it fails on second turn:

```
def get_available_subdomain
    generated_subdomain = name.downcase.gsub(/\s+|\&|\@|\#|\(|\)|\/|\.|\/|\?|\!|\"|\$|\%|\'|\*|\+|\,|\:|\;|\<|\>|\[|\]|\^|\`|\{|\}|\||\-|\~/, "") unless name.blank?
    companies = Company.where(:subdomain=> generated_subdomain)
    if companies.count == 0
      new_subdomain = generated_subdomain
    else
      new_subdomain = generated_subdomain + (companies.count).to_s 
    end
    new_subdomain
  end
```

How to make a unique method to get the expected results. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using mysql as a back-end then you can try this for searching companies with generated sud-domain like 'xyz', 'xyz1', 'xyz2' etc.

```
def get_available_subdomain
    generated_subdomain = name.downcase.gsub(/\s+|\&|\@|\#|\(|\)|\/|\.|\/|\?|\!|\"|\$|\%|\'|\*|\+|\,|\:|\;|\<|\>|\[|\]|\^|\`|\{|\}|\||\-|\~/, "") unless name.blank?
    companies = Company.where('subdomain REGEXP ?', "#{generated_subdomain}[/d]*")
    if companies.count == 0
      new_subdomain = generated_subdomain
    else
      new_subdomain = generated_subdomain + (companies.count).to_s 
    end
    new_subdomain
end
```

if database is progress then search the companies like this

```
companies = Company.where('subdomain ~* ?', "#{generated_subdomain}[/d]*")
```

if database not a mysql then I will suggested that search the company name instead of sub-domain. because you are creating the subdomain according to the company name.

```
companies = Company.where(:name => generated_subdomain)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Sanket but i don't want to restrict user on company name because company name can be duplicate multiple times

Comment: ok then go with 'companies = Company.where('subdomain ~* ?', "#{generated_subdomain}[/d]*")' solution as per your database...
check the sub-domain with regex as first two.....